# View the $PATH variable of other users

Tags: bash, unix

As a unix administrator, is there a way to view the $PATH variable of other users using bash in the system without having to switch to them?

Comment: Belongs on unix.stackexchange, I think...  why can't the "belongs on" list let you pick or enter one?

Comment: you don't, other than by deleting it and asking again over there.  But the automated tools under the close reason should be more flexible for other sites in the SE network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As root:

```
root@egg-v3:~# su - some_user_name -c env | grep PATH
```

Result:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

**Edited 10 years later**

I don't know why I didn't just write:

```bash
su - some_user_name -c 'echo $PATH'
```

or

```
sudo -u some_user_name echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Source their bashrc

```
source /home/$(USERNAME)/.bashrc
```

Comment: They might be using another shell?

Answer (score 0):

Source their `.profile` followed by their shellrc (`.bashrc`, `.cshrc`, etc based on their shell) file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Linux, if you want to get the environment for any one specific process, and you have its PID, this will work:

```
xargs -n 1 -0 echo < /proc/<PID>/environ
```

Other *nixen may or may not have similar facilities. I remember that one of the `ps` versions on Solaris had a way to get the environment variables for processes as well...